# cython cimport from another pyx file

Tags: cython

I have a project with the following structure:

```
lst_viewer/
    setup.py
    extensions/
        instrument.pxd
        instrument.pyx
        read_events.pyx
    src/
        lst_viewer/
            extensions/
                __init__.py
```

Here is my **setup.py** file:

```
import os

from Cython.Distutils import build_ext as cython_build_ext

from setuptools import find_packages, setup
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

EXTENSIONS = [
    Extension('lst_viewer.extensions.instrument',sources = [os.path.join('extensions','instrument.pyx')]),
    Extension('lst_viewer.extensions.read_events',sources = [os.path.join('extensions','read_events.pyx')]),
    ]

CMDCLASS = {'build_ext' : cython_build_ext}

setup(name="lst_viewer",
      packages=find_packages('src'),
      include_package_data=True,
      package_dir={'': 'src'},
      ext_modules=EXTENSIONS,
      cmdclass=CMDCLASS)
```

Here is my **instrument.pxd** file:

```
cdef class Instrument:
    cdef int nbdet
    
cdef class D11Instrument:
    pass

cdef Instrument get_instrument(str name)
```

Here is my **instrument.pyx** file:

```
cdef class Instrument:
    pass

cdef class D11Instrument(Instrument):

    def __cinit__(self):

        self.nbdet = 3

cdef Instrument get_instrument(str name):

    if name == "D11":
        return D11Instrument()
```

And here is my **read_events.pyx** file:

```
from instrument cimport Instrument, get_instrument

def read_events(str instrument_name):
    cdef Instrument instr = get_instrument(instrument_name)
```

I have problems with importing the `Instrument` class and `get_instrument` function from the other pyx file of the project (`read_events.pyx`). Indeed, the code compiles but, when running it, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'instrument'` error. I tried to add an (empty) `__init__.pxd` to the `lst_viewer/extensions` directory but it did not help. Would you have any idea about what I am doing wrong ?